# JQuery cache is already false but still caching

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

This code gets the current date & time and auto sets the date & time field in a form. Tried refreshing the page many times and clearing cache and it still shows the old date.

For example, when I first load the page, the time is 2:05 pm. Several minutes have passed and the field still shows 2:05pm.

I wonder if anyone experienced this issue and found a solution for this.

The project use Kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC 4.8.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '@Url.Action("GetCurrentDateTime", "Get")',
  type: "get",
  cache: false,
  success: function (resultCurrentDtTime) {
    $.each($dtTimeCurrentValue, function (key, item) {
      var dtTimepicker = $(item).data("kendoDateTimePicker");
      if (dtTimepicker !== undefined) {
        dtTimepicker.value(resultCurrentDtTime);
      }
    });
  },
  complete: function () {
    UpdateOngoingActivity();
  }
});
```

Edit: I still have no idea why it's still caching the date & time captured on the first load of the website.

But I fixed the issue by making changes to the action called "GetCurrentDateTime". Added some code that if the date & time isn't current, then set date & time to current.

Comment: Have you tried to visit the URL directly in your browser to see what the response is? Have you tried to open this page in an incognito window? Maybe the caching occurs on the server instead of in the browser?

Comment: Tried it in my browser and in incognito. It's caching the date & time captured on first load of the website.

Comment: So you get the same result also in incognito when you load that URL? Then it's not the browser that is caching the date. You'll have to look at the server side why it is caching the response. Could be some configuration in te application itself, or maybe you are using some software between the webpage and the application that is caching things.